WhatsApp API Carousel Template: Invalid Media Sample Error During Update
I am integrating the WhatsApp Business API into my website, and everything works fine during the creation of a template. However, I am encountering an issue when updating a carousel template that contains media (image) in the header.
**Here’s the data I provide during template creation, and it works perfectly:
**
{
    "category": "MARKETING",
    "components": [
        {
            "type": "BODY",
            "text": "Enter the text for your message in the language that you've selected."
        },
        {
            "type": "HEADER",
            "format": "IMAGE",
            "example": {
                "header_handle": [
                    "https://scontent.whatsapp.net/v/t61.29466-34/455307745_840177258275973_4917068164528515056_n.jpg?ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=8b1bef&_nc_ohc=JhgXpTB6hb8Q7kNvgGo4C8z&_nc_ht=scontent.whatsapp.net&edm=AH51TzQEAAAA&_nc_gid=AYrC8T5SS1pa7iuvimhJfWi&oh=01_Q5AaIDQYeMKQIW57cK89ejtgUrwADCGDyq30TZQusIPOCDmo&oe=672C6BF5"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

However, when I try to update a carousel template with similar image data, I receive the following error:

This carousel template contains a card (index=0) with an invalid media sample.

Here’s the data I send during the update, which throws the error:
{
    "category": "MARKETING",
    "components": [
        {
            "type": "BODY",
            "text": "12324"
        },
        {
            "type": "CAROUSEL",
            "cards": [
                {
                    "components": [
                        {
                            "type": "HEADER",
                            "format": "IMAGE",
                            "example": {
                                "header_handle": [
                                    "https://scontent.whatsapp.net/v/t61.29466-34/421261359_838328285127784_2325180770850864310_n.jpg?ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=a80384&_nc_ohc=CvDs5MWLqggQ7kNvgEuowZS&_nc_ht=scontent.whatsapp.net&edm=AH51TzQEAAAA&_nc_gid=AThnla93YjSTDzg4e3-2eDa&oh=01_Q5AaID-Ozb7JEZ-dNOAYQlxmks79b0nfTElne8ZqRD14ZtFV&oe=672C57BB"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "BODY",
                            "text": "234525"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "BUTTONS",
                            "buttons": [
                                {
                                    "type": "QUICK_REPLY",
                                    "text": "2452"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

What I've Tried:

The image URL is valid and works fine for non-carousel templates.
The URL is provided by Meta after uploading the media.
I suspect the issue might be related to how the API validates media for carousel components.

Question:
Why does the same image URL work for a regular template but result in an "invalid media sample" error for a carousel template? Does the WhatsApp API require a media ID for carousel updates, even if the URL is valid? How should I handle image media in carousel templates to avoid this error?
Any insights or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance!
